# PhpStorm does not show syntax errors of JavaScript in .php files

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-error, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 10.0.3. I have `test.php` file. Inside this file I have some JavaScript. What I found is, if there are any JavaScript syntax errors it does not show.

For example:

```
image.setAttribute("data-src2", "example.com/1.jpg";
```

no syntax error is shown at the end in the test.php

The entire file is

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>


<?php
$you = "sample";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //image or frame
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("data-src", "example.com");
    image.setAttribute("data-src2", "example.com";
    contentDiv.appendChild(image);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I rename the file to `text.html` then JavaScript syntax error is shown:

```
image.setAttribute("data-src2", "example.com/1.jpg";
```

it shows error saying `, or ) expected`.

How to ensure both the syntax errors are highlighted?

Comment: I can confirm that phpstorm does in fact show javascript errors in PHP file, granted you haven't put the JS in a PHP block or something

Comment: Please provide some file that can be downloaded and tested locally. Plus attach the screenshot of the place with such behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do much about this unfortunately.

ATM injection fragments (different language inside another language) seems to be treated completely differently hence most of the inspections for injected language are disabled or not run at all (*I guess* it is because each such fragment is treated as separate document which often produced quite a few false positives .. and what is done here is one form of reducing such false alarms -- just my guess).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18963 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly depends on your context. In other words, how is your JavaScript embedded on the page. If you use close tags `?>` and then carry on with some JavaScript it should be able to recognise that this part isn't PHP any more.

Comment: you mean `<?php echo 'testing';?>` Yes. All the php are enclosed

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi I guess he meant, if you are doing like `<?php echo "test"; ?><script>*js stuff*</script>` it should recognize, but if you're doing `<?php echo 'test'.'<script>*js stuff*</scipt>'; ?>` then it is treated just like text and won't be recognized.

Comment: i have edited the question with the entire file code

Comment: What PHPStorm version you're using? I have the latest and your example works fine for me.